# Python: Undetected Chromedriver used with concurrent.features keep crashing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, concurrent.futures

i have a script which open multiple undetected chromdriver instances , each one with a different profile and profile directory, and run functions on them in parallel using concurrent.features.ThredPoolExecutor.
For some reason the chrome instances the program opens keep crashing after working for a short period of time.

Here is a sample of the code which start an undetected chromedriver instance:

```
       options = ChromeOptions()
       options.headless = False
       options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={self.profile_dir}")
       options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory={self.profile_dir.split("/")[-1]}')
       options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')

       options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
       options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
         
       self.driver = Chrome(
            options=options,
            version_main=120,
            driver_executable_path='/home/hypnos/.local/share/undetected_chromedriver/undetected_chromedriver'
        )
```

then to run a function on all drivers in parallel i do:

```
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(cpu_count()) as p:
        results = list(p.map(Driver.my_function, drivers))
```

where Driver is the name of the class from where i initialize the undetected chromdriver instances and set chrome options.

My pc uses manjaro because i encountered some major problem with my os and i changed from debain11 to manjaro.
When i was using debian 11 everything worked fine!
A difference i noticed is that when i was on debian chrome automatically created a folder named "~" in my working repository which from what i understood should be some sort of profiles shared data, this folder hasn't been created in my new working repository
I tried everything possible but nothing change, added differents chrome options to try and change this behaviour but nothing worked.